# Fresco - onIntermediateImageSet from ControllerListener not being called

Tags: android, imageview, listener, lazy-loading, fresco

I'm trying to load a large size JPG progressively. I saw [this documentation](https://frescolib.org/docs/progressive-jpegs.html) using Fresco and that's exactly what I want: A blur lazy load effect. I took their code from repo [sample](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/imageformat/pjpeg/ImageFormatProgressiveJpegFragment.java) which looks like this wrapping things up:

**ImageFormatProgressiveJpegFragment.java**

```
  private void setImageUri(Uri uri) {
    mDebugOutput.setText("");
    ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
        .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(mProgressiveRenderingEnabled)
        .build();
    DraweeController controller =
        Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
            .setImageRequest(request)
            .setRetainImageOnFailure(true)
            .setPerfDataListener(mImagePerfDataListener)
            .setControllerListener(
                new BaseControllerListener<ImageInfo>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onFinalImageSet(
                      String id,
                      @javax.annotation.Nullable ImageInfo imageInfo,
                      @javax.annotation.Nullable Animatable animatable) {
                    if (imageInfo != null) {
                      QualityInfo qualityInfo = imageInfo.getQualityInfo();
                      logScan(qualityInfo, true);
                    }
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onIntermediateImageSet(
                      String id, @javax.annotation.Nullable ImageInfo imageInfo) {
                    if (imageInfo != null) {
                      QualityInfo qualityInfo = imageInfo.getQualityInfo();
                      logScan(qualityInfo, false);
                    }
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onIntermediateImageFailed(String id, Throwable throwable) {
                    mDebugOutput.append(
                        String.format(
                            Locale.getDefault(),
                            "onIntermediateImageFailed, %s\n",
                            throwable.getMessage()));
                  }
                })
            .build();
    mSimpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
  }

  private void logScan(QualityInfo qualityInfo, boolean isFinalImage) {
    mDebugOutput.append(
        String.format(
            Locale.getDefault(),
            "%s: %s, goodEnough=%b, fullQuality=%b, quality=%d\n\n",
            mDateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())),
            isFinalImage ? "final" : "intermediate",
            qualityInfo.isOfGoodEnoughQuality(),
            qualityInfo.isOfFullQuality(),
            qualityInfo.getQuality()));
  }
```

The [result](https://frescolib.org/static/videos/01-progressive-jpegs.mp4) is an output of image infos while loading it.

My code looks like the same, except for replacing logs partially:

**MyFrescoActivity.java**

```
private String IMAGE_URL = "https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73726/world.topo.bathy.200406.3x5400x2700.png";

ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(IMAGE_URL))
                .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
                .build();

        DraweeController controller =
                Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                        .setImageRequest(request)
                        .setRetainImageOnFailure(true)
                        .setPerfDataListener(this)
                        .setControllerListener(
                                new BaseControllerListener<ImageInfo>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFinalImageSet(
                                            String id,
                                            @Nullable ImageInfo imageInfo,
                                            @Nullable Animatable animatable) {
                                        if (imageInfo != null) {
                                            QualityInfo qualityInfo = imageInfo.getQualityInfo();
                                            logScan(qualityInfo, true);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onIntermediateImageSet(
                                            String id, @Nullable ImageInfo imageInfo) {
                                        if (imageInfo != null) {
                                            QualityInfo qualityInfo = imageInfo.getQualityInfo();
                                            logScan(qualityInfo, false);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onIntermediateImageFailed(String id, Throwable throwable) {
                                        Log.i("DraweeUpdate",
                                                String.format(
                                                        Locale.getDefault(),
                                                        "onIntermediateImageFailed, %s\n",
                                                        throwable.getMessage()));
                                    }
                                })
                        .build();
        simpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
    }

    private void logScan(QualityInfo qualityInfo, boolean isFinalImage) {
        Log.i("DraweeUpdate", String.format(
                Locale.getDefault(),
                "%s: %s, goodEnough=%b, fullQuality=%b, quality=%d\n\n",
                "",
                isFinalImage ? "final" : "intermediate",
                qualityInfo.isOfGoodEnoughQuality(),
                qualityInfo.isOfFullQuality(),
                qualityInfo.getQuality()));
    }
```

Still, I'm not getting responses on `onIntermediateImageSet`. The only thing being called on this listener is  `onFinalImageSet` when the image is fully loaded. Anyone has an idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are you sure your image pipeline config is set up for progressive Jpeg as shown in Showcase example?
2. If your image is coming from cache, it can be displayed at once.
3. Similarly, if your network is too fast, you won't see a progression.

You could try testing with emulator and network type set to GPRS

Comment: Not sure about 1. ; what do you mean by that? `.setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)`? ; 2. Not coming from cache, I'm reinstalling the app to test every time, which leads to 3. with my ethernet takes around 40 seconds to load a large test image such as in `IMAGE_URL`

Comment: Changed `IMAGE_URL` to a proper formatted progressive JPEG URL and it worked - https://lwstatic-a.akamaihd.net/kb/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/sleepy-purrito-progressive.jpeg